# How to mock a method to throw a particular exception in C#

Tags: c#, mocking

I'm trying to mock a method to throw a particular exception, but not able to achieve that. My method looks like -

```
    try
    {
        if (!ledgerStoreRequest.LedgerSummary.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            await _ledgerStoreHelper.WriteLedgerSummary(ledgerStoreRequest, ref storedSummaryCount, businessUnitId);
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException exception)
    {
        var errorMessage = $"Error: DynamoDB insertion has failed with duplicate key. {exception.Message}";
        _logger.LogError($"{errorMessage}");
        throw new Ascendon.SDK.Contract.Fault.InvalidPropertyException(new Fault
        {
            Code = AccountErrorCode.InsertionToLedgerSummaryTblFailed,
            Message = $"LedgerStore API failure. DynamoDB insertion has failed for " +
                      $"BusinessUnit: {businessUnitId} SubscriberID: {ledgerStoreRequest.SubscriberId}."
        });
    }
```

So I'm trying to mock **WriteLedgerSummary** to return `InvalidPropertyException` exception in an unit test. Currently the way I'm doing it is -

```
    // Arrange
    LedgerStoreHelper
        .Setup(m =>
            m.WriteLedgerSummary(It.Ref<LedgerStoreRequest>.IsAny, ref It.Ref<int>.IsAny, It.Ref<int>.IsAny))
        .Throws(new InvalidPropertyException(new Fault
        {
            Code =  GlobalErrorCode.InvalidProperty,
            Message = "some error"
        }));

    // Act
    var response = Assert.ThrowsAsync<InvalidPropertyException>(() => 
        _repository.StoreLedgerEntityAsync(BusinessUnitId,
            LedgerStoreTestConstants.LedgerStoreRequestInvoiceSummaryItem));
```

But not able to see the exception in response. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which mocking framework do you use?

Comment: `WriteLedgerSummary()` appears to be `async` because you're awaiting it. Do you need to set up the mock to be async? For example, Moq uses `ThrowsAsync()`.

Comment: I am using Moq framework @SomeBody

Comment: So is it because of the use of Throws() instead of ThrowsAsync()? @MartinCostello

Comment: If you're using Moq then use `ThrowsAsync()`.